# How did he find the "lambda" value in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

There is a pdf i found when searching about Lagrangian Multpliers, but i was not able to understand how he derived lambda from two differential equations. 
If anyone can walk me through it, i would be really grateful.
[image]

I have marked the equation he derived with a black pen.
Thanks.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform could you explain me how he has done it, i tried all the ways i know but i was not getting the result he got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivation is the following:

$2\lambda x - m\ddot{x} = 0 \rightarrow 2\lambda x^2 = mx\ddot{x}~~~~(1)$

$2\lambda y - m\ddot{y} - mg = 0 \rightarrow 2\lambda y^2 = my\ddot{y} + mgy~~~~(2)$

Now, we sum Eqs. (1) and (2):

$2\lambda (x^2+y^2) = m(x\ddot{x}+y\ddot{y} + mgy)$,

where $x^2+y^2 = l^2$. Then,

$\lambda = \frac{m}{2l^2}(x\ddot{x}+y\ddot{y} + gy)$.

Hope this helps.